# Confused about exception throwing in failed Scala futures

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
  private def getAPIResult(token: String, apiCall: String):Future[JsValue] = {
    WS.url(apiCall)
      .withHeaders("Authorization" -> ("Bearer " + token))
      .get().map(response =>
        response.status match {
          case 200 => Json.parse(response.body)
          case 401 => throw new RuntimeException("Authorization failed, we really need to handle this: " + response.body)
          case _ => throw new RuntimeException("Web service call failed: " + response.body)
        }
      )
  }
```

I need to handle the two failure cases - one where I get a HTTP 401 response and the other where something else more generic went wrong.

I'm sure I've read that it's 'bad practice' to throw exceptions in functional programming, but is that what I'm doing here? Aren't I just failing the future?

I need to be able to handle that 401 response, so I am thinking of creating a new Exception class (called something like UnauthorizedException) so that methods that call `getApiResult` can distinguish between a 401 and any other error. Before I do this though, I want to make sure that using exceptions like this is considered good practice, or if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Its perfectly valid. Future failure is propagated through compositions and can be handled in the same way as completion.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm sure I've read that it's 'bad practice' to throw exceptions in functional programming, but is that what I'm doing here? Aren't I just failing the future?

A failed future is just a value. Throwing exceptions is generally considered a bad practice because it *doesn't* behave like returning a value.

> I need to be able to handle that 401 response, so I am thinking of creating a new Exception class (called something like UnauthorizedException) so that methods that call getApiResult can distinguish between a 401 and any other error. Before I do this though, I want to make sure that using exceptions like this is considered good practice, or if there is a better way to do this.

Yes, it's perfectly fine. One problem is that it isn't obvious from the signature that UnauthorizedException needs to be dealt with separately.

For a *private* API this matters very little. If you still want to avoid it, you can do something like

```
sealed trait Response

case class Ok(value: JsValue) extends Response

case class Unauthorized extends Response

// possible
case class OtherError(e: Exception) extends Response

private def getAPIResult(token: String, apiCall: String):Future[Response] = ...
```

but of course, now all clients have to deal with it.